# std::set::iterator conversion error

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010, set

I am using an `std::set` to hold members of type `Board`, and I want to iterate over the set to do comparisons that will not work with the find method as different criteria will be used for sorting verses locating.

```
1>c:\...\project.cpp(1140): error C2440: 'initializing' : cannot convert from 'std::_Tree_const_iterator<_Mytree>' to 'std::_Tree_const_iterator<_Mytree>'
1>          with
1>          [
1>              _Mytree=std::_Tree_val<std::_Tset_traits<Board,std::greater<Board>,std::allocator<Board>,false>>
1>          ]
1>          and
1>          [
1>              _Mytree=std::_Tree_val<std::_Tset_traits<Board,std::less<Board>,std::allocator<Board>,false>>
1>          ]
1>          No constructor could take the source type, or constructor overload resolution was ambiguous
```

the thing is the iterator should not be const. the method is not const, the set is created local to the method, and I do not preface the iterator as const.

```
Thing::Thing thisFunction(int action){
    // snip 
    set<Board, less<Board>> openSet;
    // snip 
    for(set<Board>::iterator ii = openSet.begin();  // line 1140
        ii != openSet.end(); ii++){
            // snip 
    }
```

this does not make direct sense as the iterator is not declared const so it should not be trying to even consider const.

separately why is the compiler talking about a `std::_tree` when I am using a `std::set`

Comment: `std::set`s are implemented internally using `std::_tree`. BTW, `set<Board, less<Board>>` should be `set<Board, less<Board> >`(note the space between the `>` signs).

Comment: [Worksforme](http://ideone.com/ZacQj)

Comment: @fontanini: You no longer need the spaces between the `>` signs.

Comment: _Tree is the underlying data structure being used by the container.

Comment: Can you post a small program that produces this error?

Comment: @Lol4t0 Add a non-const member function to `Board` and invoke this function within the loop through the iterator variable; it doesn't work anymore

Comment: To help you, we need the full error message.  This can be found in the "output" window, and is _not_ found in the "error" window.  The "error" window only shows summaries of each error.  For this case we need more.

Comment: Deleted my answer (not in time to prevent the downvote though) but it appears VS2010 does not return `const_iterator`: I just tried it and it compiles fine.

Comment: @mooingDuck added full output of error to the question, and the error line given was from the output window

Comment: @gardian06: That error message clearly shows that the code in the question was different than your real code in one _very_ important way.  Please don't do that.  Make a small demo of the problem _that actually has your problem_ in the future.

Comment: -1 for wild goose chase.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is relatively simple, you cannot assign a

```
std::set<Board, std::greater<Board>>::iterator
```

to a

```
std::set<Board>::iterator
```

because that is *actually* a

```
std::set<Board, std::less<Board>>::iterator
```

The standard does not guarantee that these are the same type, and it is not guaranteed that there will be a conversion  between them.  In practice, these are always different types, and there is no conversion.  Thus your error.

Comment: `std::less<T>` is the default comparator, so they're not actually different types.

Comment: @DeadMG: more information was posted, showing that my stab in the dark was right.  (It _was_ a stab in the dark)

Comment: @DeadMG that only makes sense if I was using the default argument, but I am not, and therefore the compiler threw the error

Comment: @gardian06: actually, the code you showed us _does_ use the default argument.  How should we have known that you were not using the default argument?

Comment: @MooingDuck: nice psychic debugging.

Answer (score 4):

I think you have a much simpler problem than what I described below...

Try changing your `for` loop from:

```
for (set<Board>::iterator ii = openSet.begin(); ii != openSet.end(); ii++) { //...
```

to:

```
for (set<Board, less<Board> >::iterator ii = openSet.begin(); ii != openSet.end(); ii++) { //...
```

So the compiler doesn't think there needs to be a conversion.  There seems to be something else going on that's not in the code, since `less<Board>` should be the default comparator.

Maybe things would be a little clearer if you posted more of the error than just the first line.

---

`set::iterator` is always a const_iterator in VS 2010.

If you want to "modify" the element the iterator refers to, you'll need to essentially erase that element from the set, create a new element (not necessarily in that order) and insert the new element into the set.

The way it does this is buried in the `_Tree` template type that `std::set` is derived from (`_Tree` is the type that provides much of the implementation for `std::set`, `std::multiset`, `std::map`, and `std::multimap` - and that's why you're seeing a reference to `_Tree` in the error).  The `_Tree` type declares `iterator` like so (in the `<xtree>` header):

```
typedef _Tree_const_iterator<_Mybase>
    const_iterator;

typedef typename _STD tr1::conditional<
    _STD tr1::is_same<key_type, value_type>::value,
    const_iterator,
    _Tree_iterator<_Mybase> >::type iterator;
```

So if the key type is the same as the value type (such as for `std:set`, of course), iterator is typedef'ed to the `_Tree`'s `const_iterator`.

Scott Meyers discusses this in "Effective STL", "Item 22: Avoid in-place key modification in set and multiset", including how some compilers will use const_iterator-style iterators for std::set.

Comment: i don't want to delete them I want to do a comparison to them with an `operator==`that uses separate logic to the sorting operator that i used

Comment: @gardian06: So use `const_iterator` then.

Comment: I had thought the same regarding VS2010 `std::set::begin()` returning a `const_iterator` but it does not seem to be the case as I have just (re)tried it.

Comment: @hmjd: what did you try? It declares the name `std::iterator`, but in such a way that the referenced element is `const`.  Did you try to actually modify the item the iterator refers to?

Comment: @MichaelBurr, no I didn't and just did and it fails due to `const`.

Answer (score 1):

`std::set` is an ordered container, so if you're allowed to iterate over the set and muck with the internal state of the items in it, you may cause the sorting order to change, thus leaving the set in an inconsistent state. To prevent this, `std::set::iterator::operator->` returns a `const std::set::value_type*` instead of `std::set::value_type*`.

Thus, the following example compiles, but if you change `Foo::bar` to a non-const member function the compilation fails.

```
#include <set>

struct Foo 
{
  void bar() const {} // must be const
};

int main()
{
  std::set<Foo> mySet;

  for( std::set<Foo>::iterator it = mySet.begin(); it != mySet.end(); ++it ) {
    it->bar();
  }
}
```

EDIT:
To fix your original error, you need to only call `const` member functions within the loop. If you do need to mutate the state of the item in the set, you must not do it in place. As Michael Burr suggests in his [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9792169/241631) make a copy, remove the original, modify the copy and re-insert it into the set.

Comment: but wouldn't having a `const` iterator make it unchangeable because the definition of `const` is "a value/object that is not capable of change", and the error is being thrown on the assignment of the for loop not the accessing of the member

Comment: @gardian06 It does, if you want to modify a set element you must do what MichaelBurr says in his [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/9792169/241631) ... make a copy of the element, delete the original from the set, modify the copy and re-insert it into the set